# Adding letters to numbers in Pandas column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to add letters to a series of numbers in Pandas the following way:

1. In one column I have `[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3]`
2. I need to get another column where I'll have `[1a,1b,1c,2a,2b,3a,3b,3c,3d]`

In Excel it's done by applying the following formula:

```
=if(A2=A1),(A2&(CHAR(Code(right(B1,1))+1))),(a2&"a"))
```

I wonder if this Excel approach can be somehow replicated in Pandas.

Comment: You can add an extra column with cumcount and then use factorize on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are certain you don't have more repetition than the letters in alphabet, you can do this:

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3] )

letters = np.array(list('abcdefgh'))

s.astype(str) + letters[s.groupby(s).cumcount()]
```

Output:

```
0    1a
1    1b
2    1c
3    2a
4    2b
5    3a
6    3b
7    3c
8    3d
dtype: object
```